# db.collection().document().get() never returns null

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

**MainActivity.kt**

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val user = db.collection("zzz").document("ttt")
    user.get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            if (document != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot: ${document}")
            }
        }
```

My `Log` prints `DocumentSnapshot: DocumentSnapshot{key=zzz/ttt, metadata=SnapshotMetadata{hasPendingWrites=false, isFromCache=false}, doc=null}`.

No matter what `collection()` value or `document()` value I make `user` - it will never return `null`.

Why is this?

PS: The document also doesn't appear in my Firebase console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `exists()` instead:

```
if (document.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot: ${document}")
            }
```

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#public-boolean-exists-):

> `public boolean exists()`
>
> Returns
> true if the document existed in this snapshot

Comment: Thankyou this works. Curous to know in what instances `get()` would return `null`? I followed the docs (Kotlin - Android): https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document in their way of finding if a document exists so I thought that would work. Looks like those docs should be replaced with your `document.exists()` method.

Comment: Just to explain, the log that you were getting is an instance of class `DocumentSnapshot`, you can see here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.java#L92 the constructor contains the fields that you got

Comment: So the object is not null, but the field `doc` is null and if you check the method `exists` in the source code https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.java#L130 you can see that they are checking if the instance variable `doc` is null or not

Comment: Also yes im not sure why in android-kotlin they are using `!=null` might be a mistake, tagging @FrankvanPuffelen maybe he knows